# Add Javascript code to a template page in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to use this [Grid Column Carousel](http://www.anysom.dk/projects/grid-column-carousel/). I have added some code in functions.php because I would like this carousel to be only on some pages. So it requires to include a js file which load on my homepage, but also this piece of code :

```
<!-- Include the script--<
<script src="js/GridColumnCarousel.js"></script>

<!-- initialize the carousel -->
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var options = {
      elem: document.getElementsByClassName('example-1')[0],
      gridColClasses: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'
    };
     
    var gCCarousel = new GCCarousel(options);      
  };
</script>
```

How do I add it only on my page-custom.php ?

My code in functions

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_js_slider');
    function load_js_slider(){
        if ( is_page_template('accueil_page.php') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('slider_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/GridColumnCarousel.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('slider_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your page-custom.php some container like:

```
<div class="carusel"></div>
```

And in your javascript code check if this element exist - execute your code. Something like this:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('carusel')[0].length > 0) {
    var options = {
      elem: document.getElementsByClassName('example-1')[0],
      gridColClasses: 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'
    };

    var gCCarousel = new GCCarousel(options);  
   }    
  };
</script>
```